# PHP problem with array_push(mainArr, subAssociativeArr) inside a function

Tags: php, function, multidimensional-array, associative-array, array-push

the array_push(mainArr, subAssociativeArr) does not work when it is inside a function.  I need some help with this code:

```
$store=array();
$samsung=array('id'=>'10','name'=>'samsung');
$sony=array('id'=>'11','name'=>'sony');

function addOne($store, $element){
    array_push($store, $element);
}
addOne($store, $samsung);

var_dump($store); //output: empty array
```

however it works fine if without function; like the following:

```
$store=array();
$samsung=array('id'=>'10','name'=>'samsung');
$sony=array('id'=>'11','name'=>'sony');
array_push($store, $samsung);
var_dump($store); //output: array is added
```

so, what is the problem???

Comment: I never use that `array_push`  do `$store[] = $element;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return

```
function addOne($store, $element){
    $store[]=$element;
    return $store;
}
$store = addOne($store, $samsung);
```

You could also pass by reference if you want to (which is more in line with the code you have):

```
function addOne(&$store, $element){
    $store[]=$element;
}
addOne($store, $samsung);
```

Note the `&`.  Instead of copying the inputs, this is more like a pointer to the original variable, so you can update it directly.  Ether way is fine here, it's a matter of developers choice really.  For example it can be very easy to mix the two:

```
//Don't do this
function addOne(&$store, $element){ //returns null
    $store[]=$element;
}
$store = addOne($store, $samsung); //sets $store to null
```

Which you probably don't want to do, so I can see an argument for both ways.  Unless you have super big array, it probably doesn't matter much.  It's very easy to forget that a random function is pass by reference.

So use whatever method makes more sense to you.

P.S. - I refuse to use `array_push`, it's ugly and I don't like it :). Doing `$store[]=$element;` is the same as `array_push($store,$element)`, except it avoids an unnecessary function call.

Cheers.

Comment: Sure, glad I could help! - we all were new to this at one point.

Answer (score 1):

When it's in a function, you have a different scope.  While the parameters to your `addOne` function have the same name, they are actually copies of the variables passed, not references to them.

So when you `array_push()` in a function, you're only affecting the variables in that function's scope, not the outer scope.

You can either return $store, or pass the variables by reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work within a function you need a reference to the variable. A reference in PHP is defined as `&` and they are similar to "pointers" in C or C++.

Try this:

```
function addOne(&$store, $element){
    array_push($store, $element);
}

addOne($store, $samsung);
```

> A PHP reference is an alias, which allows two different variables to write to the same value. As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php